# Nullable reference types - Is flow analysis disabled for calls to 3rd party code?

Tags: .net-core, nullable-reference-types

```cs
string? storageAccountName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageAccountName");
string? storageKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageKey");
var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(storageAccountName, storageKey), useHttps: true);
MyMethod(storageAccountName, storageKey);

private static void MyMethod(string storageAccountName, string storageKey)
{
}
```

For this code VS2019 shows warning for call to `MyMethod`. Why doesn't it show it for call to `StorageCredentials` when it also accepts `string` parameters?

Answer (score 1):

My assumption here is that the `StorageCredentials` type you're using hasn't been annotated for nullability, meaning the type checker doesn't know whether a nullable value is acceptable or not. For such cases (where the type is 'oblivious') code is analysed much as it was in the pre-NRT days.

This is in contrast to your `MyMethod` method, which exists in a nullable context and therefore is known to not accept null references. Hence, the compiler issues warnings.

Over time external libraries without annotations should become fewer and fewer.

Comment: If I were author of library that contains `StorageCredentials` how would I annotate my library so that warning is generated?

Comment: You'd compile the code in a "nullable connect" using language version 8 or higher. You can add `#nullable enable` to specific files/lines, or set `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` property in your project file. The docs on this feature are pretty good.